# Countability of local maxima on continuous real-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am working through a bank of previous exams and couldn't figure a problem out to my satisfaction.

> Let $f(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\,$ be a continuous function.
>
> 1. Show that $f$ can have at most countably many strict local maxima.
> 2. Assume that $f$ is not monotone on any interval. Then show that the local
>      maxima of $f$ are dense in
>      $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: See also [Does there exist a continuous function from \[0,1\] to R that has uncountably many local maxima?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339170/does-there-exist-a-continuous-function-from-0-1-to-r-that-has-uncountably-many)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. For each $\delta>0$, the set of all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(y)<f(x)$ for all $y$ with $0<|x-y|<\delta$ is countable.  This can be seen by noting that the set contains at most one element of the interval $[k\frac{\delta}{2},(k+1)\frac{\delta}{2}]$ for each integer $k$, and these intervals cover $\mathbb{R}$.  The set of strict local maxima is a countable union of such sets, for example taking $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ ranges over the positive integers.
2. Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function that is not monotone on any interval.  We want to show that $f$ has a local maximum in every interval.  The argument is the same if the interval is $(0,2)$, so to slightly reduce notation let's work there.  Note that not being monotone in any interval means that each interval contains pairs $x_1<x_2$ and $y_1<y_2$ such that $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ and $f(y_1)>f(y_2)$.  So $(0,1)$ contains a pair $x_1<x_2$ such that $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, and $(1,2)$ contains a pair $y_1<y_2$ such that $f(y_1)>f(y_2)$.  Because $f$ is continuous, there is a point $x_0\in [x_1,y_2]$ where $f$ has its maximum value.  Because $f(x_2)>f(x_1)$ and $f(y_1)>f(y_2)$, $x_0$ is not an endpoint of $[x_1,y_2]$.  Therefore $f$ has a local maximum at $x_0$.

Comment: How do you use the continuity requirement in showing 1?

Comment: Continuity isn't needed for 1.

Comment: Then I don't see how what you've said is true. Why can't I just take $f(y)$ and move it down creating a hole in the function where all the values around it are above the new value where I moved $f(y)$. That would make the entire interval $(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ except for $y$ satisfy your stated condition and $(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ is uncountable.

Comment: @davidk01: I am saying that for each $\delta>0$, the set $\{x:\text{ for all }$y$, |x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow f(y)<f(x)\}$ is countable.  Changing the value at a single point in the domain does not affect this.  These are not the points $x$ where $f(x)>f(y)$ for some *fixed* $y$ close to $x$, but for *all* $y$ close to $x$.  Hence the statement that there can be only one such point in an interval of length less than $\delta$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: That wasn't clear in your original statement. I'll look this over.

Comment: @davidk01: I've reworded the first sentence.  I hope that it is clearer.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Ok, I understand now. Without the $\forall$ qualifier I was thinking $\{x\ :\ \exists y\ |x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow f(y) < f(x)\}$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Thank you!

@dadivk01: Thank you for the discussion.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you or your answer. Does your answer generalize to the real valued functions defined on higher dimensional Euclidean spaces $R^n, n> 1?$

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you for this answer! For the first question, if we ask "is the set of strict local maxima of a continuous function $f:R^n \to R$ is countable," then do you think your argument generalize to this case, and we get an affirmative answer? TIA

Comment: @LearningMath: It looks like you already asked as a separate question, which was a good idea!