# Number of circles with turning points of an arc

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

Let $A$ be an arc in the plane (so there is a homeomorphism $h:[0,1]\to A\subseteq \mathbb R ^2$).

Assume that $h(0)$ is the origin $o$ in the plane.

Say that a point $p\in A$ is a *turning point* if there is a neighborhood $U:=h[(a,b)]$ of $p$  such that $$\{p\}=U\cap B(o,\epsilon),$$ and either $U\subseteq \overline{B(o,\epsilon)}$ or $U\subseteq \mathbb R ^2\setminus B(o,\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon=d(o,p)$.

[image]

Let $T$ be the set of turning points in $A$.

**Question**: Is $\{\epsilon>0:T\cap \partial B(o,\epsilon)\neq\varnothing\}$ necessarily a countable set?

**Easier Question**:  Does there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $A\cap \partial B(o,\epsilon)\neq \varnothing$ and $T\cap \partial B(o,\epsilon)=\varnothing$?

Comment: Do you mean for $h(0)$ to be the origin? That seems like it contradicts your picture.

Comment: $h(0)$ is the center of the circle in the picture, which you can think of as the origin in the plane (technically there should be a line leaving it)

Comment: I don't suppose that $h$ is known to be continuously differentiable?

Comment: ...Never mind, I don't need any differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, $T$ itself is countable! Define $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ by $f(t)=|h(t)|$. Then we can identify $T$ with the strict local extrema of $f$. But there are only countably many of those, since each minimum or maximum can be uniquely bounded by a pair of rational numbers. (For details on this step, see: [Does there exist a continuous function from [0,1] to R that has uncountably many local maxima?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339170/))

Comment: oh, how clever!