# Is there $f\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ cont. converging to 0 such that $f^{-1}(y)\simeq \mathbb N$ or empty for every y in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}\newcommand{\pme}{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}\newcommand{\pmec}{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}$This is oddly specific, but in an attempt to analyze a special case of [this unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2482072/91103), this came about.

I am interested in whether a
continuous function with the following properties exists:

- $f\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$
- $f$ converges zo zero, i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0\exists x\in
    [0,\infty): f[x,\infty)\subseteq (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$
- $f$ has „countably infinite multiplicity in a neighborhood of 0“, by
  which I mean that for for every $y$ in the image and some
  neighborhood of 0, $f^{-1}(y)\simeq \mathbb N$

### Intuition

My intuition says „no“, because the only function I can imagine that
has this multiplicity property is e.g. $\sin x$, but that „diverges“
too heavily.  If we fix that by „pressing it down“, like in
$x^{-1}\sin x$, the only element of the image with countably infinite
multiplicity is $y=0$.

Note that it is vital to include $0$ in the domain, because else we
could use glue the left part of the topologists sine curve $\sin
(x^{-1})$ to the right part of $\sin x/x$, and get a desired function.

To be perfectly honest, the convergence to the right and the inclusion
of the $0$ to the left are more or less the same conditions: By using
a homeomorphism $[0,\infty)\simeq [0,1)$, the existence of such a
function is (by the convergence condition) equivalent to the ability
to add a value at $1$ to extend it to a function $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$.

### Weird, complicated attempt 1

The first observation is that for every $y\in \im f\setminus\{0\}$,
convergence guarantees $f^{-1}$ to be bounded, and thus compact.  By
being countably infinite, it has to have one accumulation point.
Let's call $x\in \mathbb R$ “horizontal accumulation point” if it is
an accumulation point of $f^{-1}(f(x))$ and refer to the set of these
as $\mathcal H(f)$.  Note that we have to have uncountably many of
them, because $\im f$ must be connected and cannot be just 0 (else
$f^{-1}(0)$ would be uncountable).

Looking at how they lie in the graph of $f$, by considering some still
uncountable subsets who are in a bounded subset in the graph
(e.g. restricting attention to some $y>\epsilon$), we can conclude
that there must be uncountably many accumulation points in the graph
of $f\vert_{\mathcal H(f)}$.

I then hoped to arrive at some contradiction like that countability
would require them to be isolated, but the only thing I came up with
was the following IMO quite interesting example:

(You may also just look at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kq0cq1irmc)

Construct $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ by partitioning
$[0,1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [2^{-n},2^{-n+1})$ on which we consider
$f_{2^{-n},2^{-n}}$ defined as follows:

\begin{align*}
  &f_{C,w}\colon [C,C+w]\to\mathbb R,\\
  &f_{C,w}(x):=
  \begin{cases}
    C+\left(x-C\right)\ \sin^2\left(\frac{2\pi w}{x-C}\right),
        &x\in [C,C+w/2] \\
    -\frac{4C}{w}\cdot\left(x-C-\frac{w}{2}\right)+C,
        &x\in [C+w/2,C+3w/4] \\
    \frac{4\left(C+w\right)}{w}\cdot\left(x-C-\frac{3w}{4}\right)\ ,
        &x\in [C+3w/4,C+w] \\
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

It is a well-defined, continuous function taking the values

\begin{align*}
  f_{C,w}(C) = f_{C,w}(C+w/2) &= C\\
  f_{C,w}(C+3w/4) &= 0\\
  f_{C,w}(C+w) &= C+w.
\end{align*}

Notably, a subset of $f_{C,w}^{-1}(C)$ is
$\{C\}\cup \left\{C+\frac{2w}{n} \mid n\in\mathbb N_{\geq 4}\right\}$,
making $C$ a horizontal limit point.

Although this is not countably infinite in *every* horizontal fibre,
it is an example of a function with a non-isolated  horizontal accumulation point (0) where the value occurs countable infinitely often.

### Weird, complicated attempt 2

I tried to weaken what is required by convergence to see what happens
„before“ everything lands in the $\epsilon$-Strip.  Convergence in
this context means the nonemptiness of

$$
\mathcal C_\epsilon := \left\{\hat x\mid f((\hat x,\infty))\subseteq
    \pme\right\},
$$

which is just the region where the $\epsilon$-convergence-criterion
holds.  It is obviously upper directed.  For all values excluded by
this strip, namely $\im f \setminus \pme$, the countable cardinality
must have its cause somewhere in $[0, \mathcal C_\epsilon]$.  This
suggests considering

$$
  \mathcal C_\epsilon^n := \left\{ \hat x\bigm| \forall y\in \mathbb R\setminus
    \pme:\: \left| f^{-1}(y)\cap (\hat x, \infty) \right| \leq n
  \right\}
$$

This just selects all points $\hat x$ for which
$f\vert_{(\hat x,\infty)}$ maps everything into $\pme$ with the
exception that each image point not in said interval may be reached at
most $n$ times.  We can easily observe
$\mathcal C_\epsilon = \mathcal C_\epsilon^0$, and that
$\mathcal C_\epsilon^n$ grows when making n larger.

However, I'm not sure what to look at after this, and especially, I'm
not sure how the demand for $0$ to be in the domain may come into
play.

---

Is there any (comparatively) simple, straightforward way to prove this?