# A continuous function on a compact set which takes any value finitely many times.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function, such that it takes any value finitely many times and $f(0) \neq f(1)$, then does there exist a point $r_{0}$ in the range such that the cardinality of $f^{-1}(r_{0})$ is odd?
(Note that the domain is compact.)

I feel that the answer is affirmative but not been able to come up with any concrete argument. I feel this because, as the function is continuous on $[0,1]$, it would attain its maximum and minimum. With out loss of generality, we can assume that the minimum is attained at $0$ and maximum is attained at $1$. In between, $0$ and $1$ it might oscillate any number of times. But the number of times minimum is attained and maximum is attained must have different parity.

Comment: Are you assuming that the range of $f$ is all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Nope. I am not assuming that the function is surjective.

Comment: What does "it takes any value finitely many times" mean?

Comment: @UmbertoP. $\forall x, |f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})|<\infty$

Comment: @Umberto P. Nope. I am not assuming that the function is surjective.

Comment: @xavierm02 You are right, about what i mean by  "it takes any value finitely many times". And this question is not same as the question you mentioned because, here the domain is compact.

Comment: @Umberto P. Yes, I mean the same, as mentioned by  xavierm02.

Comment: @Jose27 It clearly satisfy all the conditions and every value is taken exactly once, that odd number of times. That is not the question. Question is, if at all it satisfy the conditions mentioned, does it assure that there exist a value of a function which is taken odd number of times?

Comment: You mean the answer is **affirmative**, not assertive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1394264/379412). An answer of the question solved what you're considering.

Comment: @UmbertoP. The image of a continuous $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ must be a closed bounded interval.

Comment: Thank you, I know that. My concern is about the strange wording of the question.

Comment: @Toast Would you kindly elaborate?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you.

Comment: @Raghav [GQBT's first answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1404838/379412) seems to be a proof for this question.

Comment: @Toast Ok. Let me think about it.

Comment: @Toast You are right, it gives the answer.